# Getting the errro: 'Please configure android sdk' in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

I am getting the error 'Please configure android sdk" in android studio. I have tried invalidating cashes/restarting but this has not helped. I have also tried creating a new project and am getting the same error. Any thoughts on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Tools --> Android --> SDK manager and then edit the Android SDK Location.
Put the path where is your downloaded android sdk.

Usually the android studio 3.5 configure that automatically.